# Video transparency with A-Frame and Three.js

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm forwarding [this open issue](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4079) from A-Frame Github page hoping that some people may know what's going on with this issue. It's still not working with A-Frame 1.0.3 and I don't really know where to search. There are two examples on the Github issue, one working with A-Frame 0.8.0 and the other one with A-Frame 0.9.0. There are absolutely no warnings or information in the javascript console so it's kinda hard to find where the issue can be.

On version 0.8.0 it used Three v90 and on 0.9.0 it used v101. So maybe something was made between these two versions on Three but I don't understand what.

Did anybody find a way to use videos with transparency on recent versions of A-Frame and/or Three.js ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's no `three.js` issue since the following example demonstrates that webm video textures with transparency work: https://windy-rocket.glitch.me/. Tested with `R112`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mugen87 ! I saw you added to the Github issue and there was some reaction so thanks for that too :) I'll keep investigating on the A-Frame side as it became clear that it's not related to Three.js. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issues as you, and I made a shader package to solve this problem.
It works on versions > 0.9.0 check it out:
https://github.com/balataca/aframe-transparent-video-shader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the assigned texture format doesn't have the alpha channel (`THREE.RGBFormat`, you can log and check the values [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/constants.js#L96)).

You can resolve the issue by changing the format of the video texture to `THREE.RGBAFormat`:

```
videoTexture.format = THREE.RGBAFormat
```

within a custom component containing a fix like this:

```
// wait until the material is ready
this.el.addEventListener('materialtextureloaded', e => {
   // grab the material
   let material = this.el.getObject3D("mesh").material;
   // swap the format
   material.map.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
   material.map.needsUpdate = true;
})
```

working glitch [here](https://stack-59416254.glitch.me/).

Comment: Thank you! I add my element to the scene dynamically so I plugged the event listener on it at creation. 
There are just 2 slight changes I needed to do :
- I listen to the "materialvideoloadeddata" event because somehow in he process I didn't have the object3D in "materialtextureloaded" event handler.
- I have to test if material is set, I had cases where it was not.
It works anyway so thank you for your help :) 
I guess it will be made more properly in the official release!

Comment: @StéphaneAlbanese glad i could help - I've added a bit more detail to my anwser, as well as the github issue. Also totally forgot about the `materialvideoloadeddata` event :)